# Enable only the window which was opened most recently

Tags: c#, wpf, window, showdialog

I have to open multiple windows .I want only my last window to be enabled to perform user operation,though data may get added to it from code behind.On closing the current window,the next recent should get enabled.
I cant do it using showdialogue because it doesnt return unless it is closed,so I would not be able to further add the data to it from the code behind.

In all, I need a functionality like showdialogue() but where data can get added from code behind at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea :

why not use a static list to save the windows opned, then add the name of the windows to this list in window constructor, and delete it when closing window,

with this method you can disable window in activated if not the last item in this list,